# Center text and have icon aligned left

Tags: html, css

I want to have a heading with text and an icon inside a box. I'd like the icon to be on the left side, and the text to be aligned center in the box. I'm having some trouble with this. Here is what I have so far:

```css
.box {
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.icon {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100/CCCCCC&text=icon);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sed tincidunt sem, quis cursus dolor. Duis a vestibulum dui. Morbi eleifend lacus non lectus viverra semper. Aliquam sit amet rutrum erat, vel tristique augue. Mauris massa leo, facilisis
    in fermentum in, gravida vel ligula. </p>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want like this? [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rFbZC/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd give the icon absolute positioning and remove the inline-block display from the heading:

```
.icon {
    background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/ios7v2/256/Tools-Hammer-icon.png);
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position:absolute;
}
h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rFbZC/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your css rules

```
.box {
  text-align:center;
}
.icon {
 float:left;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/rFbZC/3/)

**Update**

I wouldn't use a dedicated element simply for displaying an icon. You can make use of `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements here, as follows:

```
.box {
  position:relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align:center;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.box::before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;;
  top:10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/ios7v2/256/Tools-Hammer-icon.png);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/rFbZC/4/)

Comment: The Heading text is off center in your demo. I don't want it to be centered between the icon and the border, I want it to be centered between both vertical lines in the border. Thank you though

Comment: @BillyJ. that was a quick reply.. check the update.. :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The easiest fix would be to add `margin-bottom: -6px;` or `position: relative; bottom: -6px;` to `.icon`</strike>

**EDIT**: Sorry, didn't pay attention to the part where you wanted your text aligned center.

*The quick way:*
Remove `display: inline-block;` from the `h3` and after that add `position: relative; bottom: -12px;` to `.icon`.
http://jsfiddle.net/VK7NE/

*The desired way:*
Or you could try http://jsfiddle.net/L997D/1/ - The icon and heading will alwasy align vertically disregarding the `.icon` height.